# Plotting xrray dataset in python with nondatavals = -9999

Tags: plot, dataset, missing-data, python-xarray

i have masked out tif files using vector in rasterio then opened them using xarray, concatenated them and finally created a dataset. I am trying to plot them now but the "nodatavals = -9999" affects the plots. the values as float between 0.0 and 1.0 but the plot includes -9999. kindly assist

Comment: With `xarray` you can use `.where` to mask nodata values

Comment: Sure sure!!. That worked for me now. Really appreciate.